# Is It Possible to log Selenium Webdriver Test Results to Quality Center?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, report, hp-quality-center

I am looking for a way to integrate selenium and QC to log Results.Please help me on this how it can be done. Is there any way to do this.

Thanks in advance
Rashmi

Answer (score 1):

For simple storage of results, you can do what Roland recommended and just use the API to upload the results as an attachment to some entity of your choosing.  To get a true "Run" record created in QC (like you get for Manual or QTP tests), you will need to have a Test in a Test Set that can be associated with the run results.

Perhaps the easiest option is to create a QTP/UFT wrapper test.  This test will do nothing more than invoke your Selenium test, process the results, and then write those results back to QC using the standard 'Reporter' object.

Another, more complicated, approach is to look at creating a custom test type.  This is an advanced topic, and you can refer to the QC documentation on the process.

I recommend the QTP wrapper for ease of implementation and flexibility.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. Can you please share some reference links to create QTP wrapper.  My main intention is after Test case execution i need to mark Pass/Fail the same test in QC based on results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use QC's REST API or it's OTA API.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.  Could you please some reference links / steps to get this done if u know any.

Comment: You find the API documentations with various examples in the Documentation Library of QC (HP ALM Open Test Architecture API Reference or HP ALM REST API Reference). Or use Google to find pages like this: http://fijiaaron.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/updating-test-results-in-qc-using-the-qc-ota-api-explained/.